# How can I pass Conv2D layer as a custom one to CoreML?

Tags: python-2.7, metal, keras-layer, coreml, coremltools

I read [this blog post](http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/) about custom layers and wanted to reimplement Conv2D in Metal. And I can't use [that script](https://github.com/hollance/CoreML-Custom-Layers/blob/master/convert_lambda.py) to create a custom Conv2D layer using `Lambda` in Keras for some reason.

Here's the code and debug output:

- https://www.diffchecker.com/GQRyLddR (code)
- https://www.diffchecker.com/aJQJAfJc (debug)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. The diffs you've included only show the differences between the two Keras models (one has a lambda layer with no learnable parameters, the other has a regular Conv2D layer). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'd like to implement Conv2D (with 3x3 kernel) layer in Metal (and I've found the code already), but I need to pass a custom layer (of that Conv2D) for coremltools to implement that in Metal later on, does it makes sense?

Comment: In that case, my suggestion would be to just use a Keras model with a regular Conv2D layer, convert it to Core ML, and then change the type of that layer (in the MLModel object) to custom before you save it to a .mlmodel file. That way you get to keep the weights etc but Core ML will treat it as a custom layer instead of a "real" Conv2D.

Comment: Well, could you tell write that line of code that makes this layer custom instead of Conv2D?
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(...)
layer = coreml_model._spec.neuralNetwork.layers[1]

Comment: `layer.custom.className = "CustomConv2D"`, although you'll also need to copy the parameters into the `layer.custom` structure.